# Find differences between old string and new string in typescript

Tags: typescript, angular6

For an example,

This is the line one value (old value)

This is the first untouched line (new value)

```html
This is the line one value (Old value)
<br>
This is the <span style="color:red">first untouched line </span> value (new value)
```

I want to highlight "first untouched line" of the new value in red

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037163/how-to-highlight-the-difference-of-two-texts-with-css
check this out

Comment: @arpitsharma Thanks for the comment dear. I tried by indexes. But that code have an issue. Just imagine if the old value is "this is number 123" and the new one is "this is numbers 124". Then it highlight all the characters after "numbers" :) ... Really appreciate the support friend..